# Convertir una función de JQuery a Vue

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, dom, vuetify

Uso la siguiente función hecha en JQuery que funciona perfectamente, pero estoy tratando de covertirla a Vue, pero no lo he logrado, mi función en JQuery es la siguiente:

```
$('#btnGuardarRoles').click(function () {
    $('#loading-edit-roles').show();
    var usuario = $('#rolesusuarioedit').val();
    var arr = [];
    $("#panelroles input[type=\"checkbox\"]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            arr.push({id: $(this).attr('id'), permitido: 1});
        } else {
            arr.push({id: $(this).attr('id'), permitido: 0});
        }
    });
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    $.ajax({
        url: "./model/usuario.php?dato=actualizarroles",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: jsonString, user: usuario},
        success: function (r) {
            ocultarModalRolesUsuario();
            mensajeOK(r);
        }, error: function (data) {
            mensajeWAR('NO SE PUDO EDITAR LA INFORMACION DEBIDO A UN ERROR, DETALLE: ' + data.statusText + ' - ' + data.responseText);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loading-edit-roles').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que hago es recorrer un div (#panelroles) cargado de varios checkbox para saber cuales están marcados y cuales no para cargarlos a un array, comparto imagen del div:

[image: #panelroles]

Sólo me interesa saber recorrer el div #panelroles para saber cuales check estan marcado, la parte de pasar de ajax a axios es irrelevante porque ya la tengo lista.

Comment: deberias añadir el codigo que tienes en vue y explicar que es lo que no has logrado implementar

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando vue recomiendo usar vuetify para los componentes ui en especifico el componente seria este combobox:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/#props

si tienes dudas revisa la documentación de vuetify para su implementación

código en codepen

https://codepen.io/Juan-Carlos-MA/pen/ExvjKjg?editors=1010

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: esta respuesta no responde la pregunta